# Remove Enter frame event in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, flash-cs5.5

Im on frame 3. I added my class name Tumba.as on the timeline. Tumba.as has EnterFrame event with name gameLoop.

When i go to the next frame. I want the enter frame event from the Tumba.as namely gameLoop to be removed or maybe removed the class which i added on frame 3 on the timeline cause i only want the Tumba.as to be added on frame 3 only. But removing the gameLoop is okay.

how?

Answer (score 1):

```
someObject.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,yourListenerfunction);
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to your question "how to remove an event listener". If you want to know how to solve your scope problems that is a very different question and you should ask it separately. SO is not a forum, it's a database of specific answers to specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Tumba` class why not add two methods like these?

```
public function listenToEnterFrame():void {
    // check if already has a listener so another one isn't added
    if(!hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callbackFunc);
}

public function stopListeningToEnterFrame():void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callbackFunc);
}
```